# Problems upgrading from 9.04

Tags: upgrade, freeze, 9.04

When I try to do a distribution upgrade, my mouse and keyboard completely stop responding, if I plug them back in, they continue to not respond.

Answer (score 2):

I really REALLY recommend to not do a distribution upgrade. you would need to download from each distribution upgrade than just download 11.04 and doing a backup before starting fresh. This is, assuming you wan to upgrade from 9.04 -> 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04

We are talking more than 1GB of download of distribution upgrades comparing it to downloading the 700MB Ubuntu 11.04 and doing the backup and installing it fresh (And feeling you PC as new as ever...and happy too)

Comment: The problem with that is that when I try to install the 11.04, or even the 10.04 Ubuntu refuses to boot afterwards, when I try to reinstall the installer recognizes it as Ubuntu but it never boots. Never even gets to GRUB, the only way I can get it to work is through 9.04 (ugh). (The 11.04 installer complained about not being able to install GRUB), I've had Ubuntu on this computer before, I tried to install Windows 7 and it ate my ubuntu partition :(

Comment: Ok what error does is popup when installing. Can you select from the Live CD/Live USB main menu "Try Ubuntu" but before pressing enter press F6 and remove the last part of the line that reads "quiet splash --" then press enter. It will start loading but showing you what is happening step by step. There are also several options to try when you press F6 since a small menu will appear. If you press ESC when that menu appear then you can eliminate the options i mentioned above.

Comment: The Live CD works just fine, but after install nothing boots.

Comment: There was an error message in the 11.04 install about GRUB not being able to install

Comment: Can you post the error here. When did it say it, what did it say?